# Convert office 2003 excel file to office 2007 in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, excel-2007, export-to-excel, rdlc

It is possible to convert in asp.net c#.
I have a brownfield asp.net 3.5 (2.0) application which uses RDLC to then export a 2003 excel file.
I wish to create a new memorystream converting to the newer 2007 and above format

xls to xlsx is what I am wanting to do.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you wanted to search. [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1391579.aspx/1)
Something like excel convert is not possible, but what you need the most is your logic to found out the possible